# Can't load resources file from jar

Tags: java, jar, resources

I'm using configuration JSON file stored in `src/test/resources/config.json`.

I'm getting it like this:

```
String configFile = this.getClass().getResources("config.json").getPath();
```

I have `getPath()` method, because  I need its `String` value, then check if file exists and finally parse it.

In Eclipse IDE everything works fine, because I parse file `/bin/config/config.json`, but when I create JAR file, the path is `program.jar!/config/config.json` and function `!Files.exists()` returns false.

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of referencing the file by it's path,  when you use the resources loader you should open the file's InputStream.

Instead of `.getResources("config.json").getPath();`

Try using `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.json");`  If the stream that is returned is null then the resource does not exist.

This way even if the resource is packed into a jar, the classloader will always return you the correct thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can't access a path inside a jar using the `File`-class, since it's not a native file-system resource and reading from a jar requires a lot more than reading an ordinary file (unpacking etc).

So to load a file from a jar the best way you can go is using a classloader: it knows how to search jar-files, how to unpack them etc.

So to read the file you better use

```
InputStream configStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.json");
```

You'll know the file doesn't exist on your classpath when `configStream` is `null`.

The only thing that's missing now is the `String`-representation of the path, but I can't think of a usecase where you'd actually need it - and if you really, really need it you can use your old way to get it.

P.S.: I also can't think of a reason why you would have to check if the file exists when you got the path - if the file didn't exist `this.getClass().getResources("config.json").getPath();` should fail with a `NullPointerException`!!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. The reason is that I have two possibilites how to load config file. First is from resources (default) and second is from user defined path to json file when program is run from command-line (as args[0]). But if I little bit change code it could works. I'll see.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you are using mvn to build the jar

you can build the jar with all the dependency. This will pack the dependent jars and files needed. You can read 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html

in gradle 
https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin

Comment: I'm using Gradle, but I can't deploy JAR file with dependencies, something went wrong with FatJar plugin. So I create JAR within Eclipse but last problem is with resources.

Comment: So, shouldnt you be solving the Fatjar plugin problem ?