# main class in fat jar fails when using static factory method, but works fine in IDE

Tags: static, factory-pattern, fatjar

I have a small project that i'm using shadowJar to create a fatjar to run from command line..

the main class entry point gets  ref to class in the project using static factory method like this

```
static void main (args){


MessageSystemClient mclient = MessagePlatformFactoryProducer.getFactory().getMessagePlatformInstance("WLS")

println "howdi "....
}
```

when i run the fat jar at the command line i get an error like so

```
PS D:\Intellij-projects\message-platform-client\build\libs> java -jar message-platform-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --send "hello" -r
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\Intellij-projects\message-platform-client\build\libs\message-platform-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!\ApplicationConfig.groovy (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at groovy.util.CharsetToolkit.<init>(CharsetToolkit.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.newReader(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1741)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.getText(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:592)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$1013.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.doMethodInvoke(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:298)
        at com.softwood.implementation.MessagePlatformFactory.getMessagePlatformInstance(MessagePlatformFactory.groovy:29)
        at com.softwood.client.AbstractMessagePlatformFactory$getMessagePlatformInstance.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
        at com.softwood.cli.Launcher.main(Launcher.groovy:40)
```

however if i comment out the static factory call - and regenerate then the fat jar runs ok and prints the howdi to the console.

if i uncomment the factory lookup again, and just run the Launcher class in the   IDE the code works fine with no problems

so why is it failing as a fatjar, but works as ordinary project?.  secondly assuming its something to do with fatjar zip approach - how do i overcome this ?

I had a earlier version of the project that just directly called static methods on project classes,  and that works fine as a fatjar - so the problem is with the static factory behavior inside a fatjar .

i tried to load the classes using

```
Launcher.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass ("<various factory classes etc>")
```

the classes would load ok - but the factory call itself still breaks as shown above in stack trace

Can any one help me over this problem  please?

Answer (score 0):

Found it - in my factory methods I was doing a call like this to load a configFile:

```
File configFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("ApplicationConfig.groovy")?.getFile())
```

However as per [related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362943/cant-load-resources-file-from-jar), this won't work in a fat jar as there's no full file system in the jar.

What you have to do is use line like:

```
InputStream configStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("ApplicationConfig.groovy")
```

as this will work in the jar, and test if stream is null (can't find your resource in the fatjar) or you get the stream itself which you can read the text from the file.

Took a while, but now back on I think.

Comment: Hi William. I wonder if I could trouble you to take more care with spelling and case? Stack Overflow is not a chatroom where "anything goes" - it is effectively documentation presented in Q&A form. I thought about downvoting this, since I've made many case and apostrophe fixes to your posts in the past, but it might be fairer if I can flag it to you first. Thanks!